# How do I hide developer tab

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in Advance!

I have designed a spreadsheet for tracking employee attendance,instead of paying for a subscription. It is designed with different password levels depending on how much access you are allowed. EX supervisors can enter daily attendance recorders but cannot submit changes or add/delete employees. Besides having sheet protection for which cells can be selected/info entered, I have also a workbook protection for denying access to functions, such as make sheets hidden/visible and add rows/columns. What I still need this code to do is make the developer tab not visible. I have seen plenty of suggestions saying to use XML for ribbon customization.

I do not want to use XML because:

1. I have yet to see how to incorporate it into VBA
2. It is a separate file
3. lack of familiarity
4. I am using Excel 2007 which is no longer supported by MS, thus finding information
   very difficult (maybe I'll update some day)

Here is my workbook protection code.

```
Sub Workbook_Lock()

Dim set_work_book_password As String
Dim work_book_password As String

set_work_book_password = "Password"

top:
work_book_password = InputBox("Enter Password to Protect Workbook", "Workbook Lock Password", "password")

If work_book_password = "" Then
    MsgBox "Protection Canceled"
    Exit Sub
End If

work_book_password_re_entered = InputBox("Verify Password", "Workbook Lock Password", "password")

If work_book_password_re_entered = "" Then
    MsgBox "Protection Canceled"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not (work_book_password = work_book_password_re_entered) Then
    MsgBox "Passwords do not match" & vbNewLine & "Retry"
    GoTo top
End If

If Not (set_work_book_password = work_book_password) Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect Predefined Password" & vbNewLine & "Please use Predefined Password"
    GoTo top
End If

ThisWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=True, Password:=work_book_password
Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You may be able to disable access to the Visual Basic Editor -- information is [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28228629/prevent-users-from-opening-the-excel-vba-window-2010.html)

Comment: A few notes: 1. 2016 is the last office before O365 and it's great. Upgrade to 2016 before it is not available anymore. 2. Password protections of VBA or Excel is a futile effort. There is nothing you can do to secure your code or workbook. 3. Why would you make your own password prompts that are even less secure than the built in ones?

Comment: HackSlash - 1. I have considered upgrading to 2016 and have used it at work (yes it is great), I'm just poor and can't afford. Although it looks like 2019 (and only a little bit more expensive) might not require a subscription like 365, I just need to look into it to see which would be better to get for home use. 2. Like I described above this is for keeping track of employee attendance and I'm just thinking into the future to keep lower level people from messing with abilities that they shouldn't unless they have received the necessary training to get the next level up password.

Comment: HackSlash - 3. I have a series of buttons that depending on their security level will require different passwords before running the code, such as delete employee requires knowing 3 passwords to run. I have a function that calls this code to completely lock everything after fixing code and other issues. I also have an unlock version of this as well. If you are saying that it is less secure because of this line: set_work_book_password = "Password" , then that is just for posting on here so that it could run for anyone testing out the code. I would never have the password be password.

Comment: PeterT - I will tryout your link to see if that option would be beneficial as well. Specifically if there ends up being an employee who is excel savvy a knows about the developer tab. But I still want to hid the tab as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I still need this code to do is make the developer tab not visible.

To hide developer tab using VBA, try this

```
Application.ShowDevTools = False
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if I want to allow showing dev tools through a password

Comment: @Shomaail: You can use a Userform to accept the password and then sshow/hide the developer tab